# Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onPermissionsChecked(p0:

Tags: kotlin

Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onPermissionsChecked(p0: MultiplePermissionsReport!): Unit defined in com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener
Unresolved reference: areAllPermissionsGranted
Unresolved reference: isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rbc8.png)

```
public fun requestPermissions() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
        .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS) 
        .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
            fun onPermissionsChecked(multiplePermissionsReport: MultiplePermissionsListener) {
                if (multiplePermissionsReport.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                    getContacts()
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                        "All the permissions are granted..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                // check for permanent denial of any permission
                if (multiplePermissionsReport.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                  
                    showSettingsDialog()
                }
            }

            fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                list: List<PermissionRequest?>?,
                
            ) {
                
            }
        })
        .withErrorListener(object : PermissionRequestErrorListener {
            fun onError(error: Dexter?) {
                
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occurred! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                   .show()
           }
       }) 
        .onSameThread().check()
            .withErrorListener{
                fun onError(error: Dexter?) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error occurred! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                        .show()
                }
            }
            .onSameThread().check()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `fun onPermissionsChecked(multiplePermissionsReport: MultiplePermissionsListener)`, but interface [MultiplePermissionsListener](https://javadoc.io/static/com.karumi/dexter/2.3.1/com/karumi/dexter/listener/multi/MultiplePermissionsListener.html) requires argument of type MultiplePermissionsReport.
You need to update the type of the argument.